# What parts are bad in my printer (sample print provided)?

Tags: printing, printer

I would appreciate any insight as to what the failing components of my printer (Samsung CLP-315) might be.

The sample print:
[image: https://files.catbox.moe/s37czi.jpg]

The expected print:
[image: https://files.catbox.moe/5p5lza.jpg]

Note: The two drops of water are just that; the printer did not do that. I am using aftermarket toner. I have cleaned the transfer belt and drum with alcohol. I also replaced the roller.

Comment: You've had your money's-worth out of it. Recycle it & buy a new one. All you're going to be doing at this age is fixing each bit as it breaks down, like trying to keep an old nondescript car on the road long past its zero value date. I had a CLP. It was great. It lasted a decade. When it died I bought a newer, better one. Uses a quarter the electricity, has better networking & many other features, was cheaper than buying new ink. Re-building a printer from separate components is going to be ten times the price of a new machine.

Comment: This looks very much like a drum issue to me.  I also had a CLP printer. I got it cheap a long time ago.  It was rebadged HP crap and I agree with Tetsujin about replacong it - although I replacrd mine with a second hand high end brother mfc that had been fully reconditioned with new ink for chump change (best printer ive bought) - The thing is my new second hand printer is the last decent model predating these "drm" cartridges  and I can use dirt cheap replacement cartridges without hacks.

Comment: +1 for the drum, and possibly the fuser too. By the time you've replaced the drum, toner and fuser, you may as well have bought a new printer.

Comment: @spikey_richie judging from the vertical lines that go all the way thru, the glass in front of the laser also seems to be dirty. Also it seems that the printer got moved without any care and all of the internals were covered in toner dust. Definitely time to get a new one, except you have an excess of time and money.

Comment: @mashuptwice yes, or excess toner dust in the fuser and/or roller.

Answer (score -4):

Looks like it may be bad toner cartridges and/or faulty fuser.

Either way, it will cost you more to diagnose and repair than it would to buy a new LaserJet printer.

Go buy a new printer and recycle this one.

Comment: There is no evidence this is a toner issue .

Comment: You don't have all 4 toners go faulty in the middle of a print